# Where do primitives for drawing come from?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, primitives

I'm currently wondering how packages like `tikz` can possibly work. I've read the *TeX Book* and found no evidence of TeX primitives capable of drawing things. LaTeX is just a collection of macros so the use of LaTeX cannot provide this capability.

Is the *pdfTeX* engine providing the primitives necessary for producing drawings? If yes, which are those primitives?

Comment: for pdftex it is `\pdfliteral` then tikz injects literal pdf fragments, just as graphicx does for image inclusion, or `color` does for color

Comment: TeX also provides `\special` features.  OTOH, `picture` and `pict2e` do graphics using special fonts.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `pict2e` uses `\special` or `\pdfliteral` rather than specialized fonts, so it is able to lift the restrictions of legacy `picture` mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My TeX Live on windows has among others the following folder

```
c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/
```

Here you'll find many files like `pgfsys-pdftex.def`, `pfgsys-dvips.def`, `pgfsys-luatex.def`, `pgfsys-xetex.def` and so on...

Depending on how you are compiling your file, the system loads the appropriate `.def` file. There the TeX instructions are "translated" into driver-dependent instructions. For example, `pgfsys-pdftex.def` has

```
\def\pgfsys@invoke#1{\pdfliteral{#1}}
```

while `pgfsys-luatex.def` has

```
\def\pgfsys@invoke#1{\pdfextension literal{#1}}
```

and `pgfsys-dvips.def` has

```
\def\pgfsys@invoke#1{\special{ps\ifpgfsys@ps@boxmode\else:\fi: #1}}
```

Analogously, *all* macros are in the end mapped into the appropriate driver instruction. For example, `pgfsys-common-pdf.def` (used by `pdftex` and `luatex` have

```
\def\pgfsys@miterjoin{\pgfsysprotocol@literal{0 j}}
\def\pgfsys@roundjoin{\pgfsysprotocol@literal{1 j}}
\def\pgfsys@beveljoin{\pgfsysprotocol@literal{2 j}}
```

while `pgfsys-common-postscript.def` has

```
\def\pgfsys@miterjoin{\pgfsysprotocol@literal{0 setlinejoin}}
\def\pgfsys@roundjoin{\pgfsysprotocol@literal{1 setlinejoin}}
\def\pgfsys@beveljoin{\pgfsysprotocol@literal{2 setlinejoin}}
```

and so on.

pdfTeX is in a sense its own driver, so it can use `\pdfliteral` directly. On the other hand, going using e.g. dvips means that the Ti*k*Z macros just use appropriate `\special` nodes: these are just shipped out, and it is the job of dvips to use them to actually print something.

Comment: Aside: Is `\pdfliteral` something like `q 0 0 1 0 0 rg 0 0 m` and such things as I see as "whatsit" code? That is, does `\pdfliteral` mean a string of characters (not obvious to end users) that is written directly into the PDF (or pre-PDF) file?

Comment: @rallg Not sure I understand the first question but for the second I'd say yes, though I'm no PDF expert. In Knuth TeX you would just have a `\special` whatsit node which is written into the dvi file and which your printing driver (xdvi, dvips, dvipdf(m)(x),...) interprets. `\pdfliteral` is a pdfTeX primitive but I assume it makes a whatisit node like like `\special`does.